# 2 AverageTimer32 Performance Counter

Tags: c#, .net, windows, console-application, performancecounter

How can I define and use two AverageTimer32 performance counters in one application (.exe)?

Additional Notes:
I am trying so measure spent time on different parts of an operation.

I have an AverageTimer32 performance counter and an AverageBase. It works.

Now I want to add a second AverageTimer32 performance counter. It does not work even if I add another AverageBase counter. I think I am mistaken about something. Code sample is really appreciated.

This is the different parts of the code:

```
_AverageDuration = new PerformanceCounter();
_AverageDuration.CategoryName = CategoryName;
_AverageDuration.CounterName = "average time per operation";
_AverageDuration.MachineName = ".";
_AverageDuration.ReadOnly = false;

_AverageDurationBase = new PerformanceCounter();
_AverageDurationBase.CategoryName = CategoryName;
_AverageDurationBase.CounterName = "average time per operation base";
_AverageDurationBase.MachineName = ".";
_AverageDurationBase.ReadOnly = false;
...
CounterCreationDataCollection counters = new CounterCreationDataCollection();
...
CounterCreationData avgDuration = new CounterCreationData();
avgDuration.CounterName = "average time per operation";
avgDuration.CounterHelp = "Average duration per operation execution";
avgDuration.CounterType = PerformanceCounterType.AverageTimer32;
counters.Add(avgDuration);

CounterCreationData avgDurationBase = new CounterCreationData();
avgDurationBase.CounterName = "average time per operation base";
avgDurationBase.CounterHelp = "Average duration per operation execution base";
avgDurationBase.CounterType = PerformanceCounterType.AverageBase;
counters.Add(avgDurationBase);
...
PerformanceCounterCategory.Create(CategoryName, "Category for Receiver", PerformanceCounterCategoryType.Unknown, counters);
...
AverageDuration.IncrementBy(performanceCounterwatch.ElapsedTicks);
AverageDurationBase.Increment();
```

Comment: BTW, you may consider something like [Using XSLT to Generate Performance Counters Code](http://rusanu.com/2009/04/11/using-xslt-to-generate-performance-counters-code/) to avoid repeating all the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of adding them is critical. You must add the Average, then its corresponding base, then the second average and then the second corresponding base.

Comment: Also I (think) had to remove the category and add it again with new performance counters.